# modifications to main.css were lost after executing gulp install in jhipser

Tags: css, angularjs, jhipster

I am new to jhipster. I added another css property in main.css file and called it in the home.html. But after running gulp install command that modification was disappeared from the main.css. So how to save that modification even after run that command?

Comment: Do you use sass with your project? If you are unsure, you can check by looking in .yo-rc.json for "useSass"

Comment: yes. Then what happened? Do we need to modify only sass?

Comment: ok thanks by changing main.scss, it works

Answer (score 2):

When using the SASS option in JHipster, you should make all of your CSS or SCSS changes in `main.scss`.

During the build process, `gulp` (AngularJS) or `webpack` (Angular) will compile `main.scss` into `main.css`, replacing the contents of that file.  This is also why `main.css` is included in `.gitignore`.